# Why is most of the browser frame time empty yet the frame still takes more than 16ms

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I'm trying to make an animation where the frame rate is below 16ms. For many of the frames I get this pattern:

[image]

Where the majority of the frame is empty. The yellow is my requestAnimationFrame script, then rendering and painting. But why, when this only takes a small fraction of the frame time, is the frame still nearly 20ms long?

Here's some code that demonstrates it:

```
var square = document.getElementById('square');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    square.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px';
  square.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px';
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5peLpf53/

Screenshot of timeline from fiddle:

[image]

Comment: we need a [mcve] please!

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks, I've added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, browsers run at 60 fps maximum. This is the same as once every 16.6 ms. There is no need for any higher, since many monitors are not higher than 60 Hz.

requestAnimationFrame  just tells the browser to run some code before the next repaint of the screen. You can't update the screen any faster than this.

If you have some logic that requires more frequent update, then you should put it somewhere else.

Comment: If they run at 60 fps maximum then how come there are some frames well under that? I've found frames as low as 8ms today.

Comment: You mentioned 16ms and requestAnimationFrame specifically, so I thought this might be the reason. I don't know why you are experiencing what you do. Maybe look up the specs of the browser you are using.